# android - wakelock sleep confusion

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I'm a tad confused as to what exactly happens to the device when a wake is called from alarmmanager. Does the phone screen come on/light up?

I'm thinking of having things run overnight and I think it's pretty bad if the phone suddenly kicks into life and the screen comes on, potentially waking the user up!

Or am I not fully understanding a wake or wake lock?

Thanks

Russ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the phone screen come on/light up?

`AlarmManager`, when it processes a `_WAKEUP` alarm, uses a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`, which does not light up the screen.

Answer (score -1):

The wake feature will make the phone screen turn on and the wake lock would stop the  phone screen from dimming down or turning off.

Comment: When you have the answer you wanted please select it as your accepted answer.That way users will come back and help you again in the futre

Comment: I will, but as you have both given virtually opposing answers, I'll probably have to code it myself before I know.

Comment: No - the question was for an alarm manager wakelock - you should delete this - @RussWheeler correct answer above by commonsware